# Ajax call on disabled component in JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf

It seems that ajax call doesn't get invoked on disable components. Is there any alternative?

Here is my code. Please tell if i am doing some other mistake..

```
<h:inputText id="inputId" disabled = "true">
   <f:ajax event="mouseover" listener="#{promotionDetailManagedBean.getToolTipInfo}"
      execute="@this" render="priceConTooltip" >
   </f:ajax>
</h:inputText>
```

Thxx
Tarun Madaan

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you're asking why it doesn't work when the component is disabled?  Doesn't appear disabled in your source here.  If it was disabled, why would you expect it to work?

Comment: Using ajax to display tooltips is very inefficient. Just set the `title` attribute and use a jQuery plugin like qTip to transform it into a fancy looking tooltip.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch : I have edited the code and added disabled attribute. Thxx 4 reply.

Comment: @BalusC: Actually i have some other implementation of tooltip and data is to be populated through ajax because its about 200 rows in tooltip and for that i am using scroll in tooltip.( I know requirement seems very silly but could not convince client.) And my input text is disabled but i want to show how the value was calculated in it.So need to have ajax call.. Please tell what to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Make it `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

If you need it to have the style of a disabled input, just throw in some CSS to achieve that. E.g.

```
input[readonly] {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on Mojarra 2.1.9. Did you remove the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: I am using Mojarra 2.1.8. Is there some issue with that version. (I can't upgrade to 2.1.9)